# WCF service timeout setting

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, timeout, wshttpbinding

I have a ASP.NET 4.0 app that is calling a WCF service. For testing, the closeTimeout, openTimeout, receiveTimeout, and sendTimeout values in the wsHttpBinding binding are all set to 01:00:00.

When I ran a test in which the service took 5 minutes 40 seconds, I could see the correct results of the WCF service in the app event log. However, the app did not process the results.

In subsequent *identical* tests in which the WCF service took less than 4 minutes, I could see the same correct results in the app event log, but the app processed the results correctly.

I'm thinking there's another timeout setting I don't know about. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: did you try the OperationTimeout setting

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I read the sendTimeout value is used to initial OperationTimeout, and the sendTimeout is set to an hour. Can it be set via web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `OperationTimeout` property of the WCF service client where it is instantiated:

```
MyWCFServiceClient client = new MyWCFServiceClient();
client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
client.Open();
```

The above will set the timeout to 10 minutes